# Swift: Geofire Instanciation error after Firebase 3 upgrade

Tags: swift, firebase, geofire

Since upgrading to Firebase 3, last line in below code is giving error:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let locationsRef = ref.child("locations")
let geoFireQuery = GeoFire(firebaseRef: locationsRef)
```

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Comment: Try doing a clean project and try again. cmd + shit + K and try?

Comment: What is your podfile?

Comment: I have installed manually. No pod file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoFire needs to be updated to version 2 also in order to make it work with Firebase 3.
Follow the instructions below to fix this issue:

1. Download zip source from here: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc
2. Unzip it and go to /GeoFire/API folder
3. Copy all 4 files in it
4. Go to your project and navigate to your GeoFire.framework
5. Navigate to Headers folder, you will see the same 4 files there
6. Replace them
7. Clean your project, it is now fixed.

Please note that as of today there is no pod available for GeoFire 2

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your pod file

`pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'`